# Two almost identical aspects cause strange issue

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

I am using aspectj and have two almost identical aspects defined, the first one works just fine whether the second fails during compilation as below:

```
[WARNING] advice defined in com...RolesAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
```

First aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class RoleAspect {

    @Before("requireRolePointcut(requireRole)")
    public void requireRole(JoinPoint joinPoint, RequireRole requireRole) throws Throwable {
        //TODO
    }

    @Pointcut("@annotation(requireRole)")
    public void requireRolePointcut(RequireRole requireRole) {
    }
}
```

Second aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class RolesAspect {

    @Before("requireRolesPointcut(requireRoles)")
    public void requireRoles(JoinPoint joinPoint, RequireRoles requireRoles) throws Throwable {
        //TODO
    }

    @Pointcut("@annotation(requireRoles)")
    public void requireRolesPointcut(RequireRoles requireRoles) {
    }
}
```

Annotation RequireRole:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value={ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface RequireRole {
    String value();
}
```

Annotation RequireRoles:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value={ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface RequireRoles {
    String[] value();
}
```

Any help is really appreciated. I tried many different annotations but the second always fails so there must be something maybe with it.

Comment: Hello. You asked a question, I answered it. I would appreciate some feedback. This is what polite people usually do on SO. So please check my answer, then accept + upvote if you think it is correct (I certainly do).

Answer (score 0):

The aspect does not **fail**, what you see is just an AspectJ compiler warning telling you that the pointcut does not **match**.

Unfortunately you are not showing

- your full aspect code
- and also no target class(es) with package names(!).
- Same goes for your annotations: no package names.

I.e. you have omitted the information needed to analyse your problem.

Thus, for now I can only tell you to fix your pointcut in order to make it match what you want to intercept - or edit your question in order to show it to me and notify me with a comment. Then I can take a second look and provide more concrete hints.